# rails method to get the association name of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to find out what associations a model has? Take these 2 models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
Post.has_many #=> ['comments', ...]
Post.belongs_to # => ['user']
Comment.belongs_to # => ['commentable']
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You're looking for [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#M001861).

So in short:

```
Post.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

...will give an array (of object with attributes like `name`, etc) of all `has_many` associations.

Answer (score 1):

The following will list all the associations for a particular instance of Post.

```
#app/models/post.rb
  def list_associations
    associations = []
    User.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name).each do |assoc|
      association = send assoc
      associations << association if association.present?
    end
    associations
  end
```