# Table associations in Rails - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there any way to get a table association from a `rails console`? I want to check the relation to the specific table from the console directly, rather than connection to a database.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What do you mean by `get a table association` and `check the data related to the specific table`?

Comment: For a better explanation, I would like to get the output of the association(relation) for the specific table from the console. In other words, see if there is any relation with other tables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024205/rails-method-to-get-the-association-name-of-a-model

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have `User` and `Post` model with respective tables `users` and `posts` in DB. User `has_many :posts` association defined, then you could do:

```
$ rails console
```

```
u = User.all.first # or 
User.last # or 
User.find(1)
```

```
u.posts # or
u.posts.first # or
u.posts.where(...)
```

Provided you have seed the data

Comment: This only provides data belonging to a relation, what I try to see if that the relation itself. Edited the question.